# AJAX javascript not firing asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, controls

When I add new controls to my web application, the javascript does not fire. I've tried many solutions, but none of them work. Specifically, the accordion/accordion pane from the AJAX Control Toolkit does not slide up/down. Also the FileUploadProgress control from Obout uses javascript functions which do not fire. If I open a new web application project and try all this, it works just fine. My project is quite large so I cannot start from scratch. Can someone please tell me what could be wrong with my project? I have no errors. The javascript simply does not fire. Please help. I am using asp.net c#.

EDIT:

Here is the code for file upload progress control. I do have alert statements but they do not fire.

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

    function Clear() {
        alert("here1");
        document.getElementById("<%= uploadedFiles.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "";
    }

    function ClearedFiles(fileNames) {
        alert("here2");
        alert("Cleared files with bad extensions:\n\n" + fileNames);
    }

    function Rejected(fileName, size, maxSize) {
        alert("here3");
        alert("File " + fileName + " is rejected \nIts size (" + size + " bytes) exceeds " + maxSize + " bytes");
    }
</script>

<input type="file" name="myFile1" runat="server"/><br/>
<input type="file" name="myFile2"  runat="server"/><br/>
<input type="file" name="myFile3"  runat="server"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="mySubmit" /><br/>
<br/>
<fup:FileUploadProgress ID="FileUploadProgress1" 
   OnClientProgressStopped   = "function(){alert('Files are uploaded to server');}"
   OnClientProgressStarted   = "Clear"
   ShowUploadedFiles         = "true"
   OnClientFileRejected      = "Rejected"
   OnClientFileCleared       = "ClearedFiles"
   runat                     = "server"
>
 <AllowedFileFormats>
      <fup:Format Ext="gif" MaxByteSize="10240"/>
      <fup:Format Ext="jpg" MaxByteSize="10240"/>
      <fup:Format Ext="jpeg" MaxByteSize="10240"/>
      <fup:Format Ext="png" MaxByteSize="10240"/>
 </AllowedFileFormats>
</fup:FileUploadProgress> 
<asp:Label runat="server" id="uploadedFiles" Text="" />
```

And here's the code-behind for it:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = Page.Request.Files;

            uploadedFiles.Text = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                if (file.FileName.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (uploadedFiles.Text.Length == 0)
                        uploadedFiles.Text += "<b>Successfully uploaded files: </b><table border=0 cellspacing=0>";

                    uploadedFiles.Text += "<tr><td class='option2'>" + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) + "</td><td style='font:11px Verdana;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + file.ContentLength.ToString() + " bytes</td></tr>";
                }
            }

            if (uploadedFiles.Text.Length == 0)
                uploadedFiles.Text = "no files";
            else
                uploadedFiles.Text += "</table>";
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: place some alert message and see and also place some code in your question. So we can see how you are calling the javascript function and will tell where is the wrong

Comment: does your javascript and the javascript libraries you need load on the client?

Comment: What do you mean by "add new controls"? UserControls you add to the project? Classes that inherit from Control that you just added?

Comment: I added sample code in my question. @user277498: I'm not sure if the javascript libraries load. Since the alert statements don't fire, I assume they don't load.

Comment: @sq33G: By new controls, I mean controls from the ajax control toolkit or the FileUploadProgress control from Obout. Basically asp.net controls that aren't there by default.

Comment: Does an alert outside of any function execute on load?

Comment: @sq33G: Yes it works if I put it like this: <body onload="load()"> and then the javascript load() function with an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is because you are passing anything to your javascript functions. :

Here is what you have. :

```
OnClientProgressStarted   = "Clear"
ShowUploadedFiles         = "true"
OnClientFileRejected      = "Rejected"
OnClientFileCleared       = "ClearedFiles"
```

Here is what I think you should probably have. :

```
OnClientProgressStarted   = "Clear();"
ShowUploadedFiles         = "true"
OnClientFileRejected      = "Rejected();"
OnClientFileCleared       = "ClearedFiles();"
```

Also, several of those functions require parameters, which I did not list above......Hopefully this helps you.